# MongoDB ConnectionException: Could not connect to ac-pxlxpqi-shard-00-00.kubcpel.mongodb.net:27017

Tags: database, mongodb, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to connect Mongodb Atlas to my flutter app but it gives the error in the title

When connecting mongodb, I used the link below and instead of password I entered the password I created.

```
const MONGO_URL ="mongodb+srv://orhanweb:f!YiBfKA7aU86ss@cluster0.kubcpel.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Where does this error come from?

[image]

I was waiting for it to connect to Mongodb Atlas

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Maybe a firewall issue. Did you white-list your IP in Atlas?